# Using alignParentStart

Tags: android, layout

I'm trying to make the icon & text components in my navigation drawer swap places depending on the language's read direction. I've tried using the start and end replacements for left and right but it isn't taking effect. I've changed my phone's language to Arabic and I can see it causing the effect I want in the Google music (or whatever it's called) app's drawer but not in mine. Here's my layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc_list_item_icon"
        android:src="@drawable/bubble_arrow"
        android:alpha="1"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <com.my_app.android.views.TextViewPlus
        android:id="@+id/nav_item"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:lineSpacingMultiplier="0.8"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/icon"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_small"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:paddingStart="0dp"
        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
        app:customFont="Roboto-Light.ttf"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What is the minSDK version you're using?

Comment: 14, though my test device runs on 21

Comment: I've brought up the minSDK to 17 just to make sure that's not it; the issue persists

Comment: @FabCastel Do not bring your min sdk up. You are limiting the range of the users you are going to support.

Comment: That was only in an attempt to hone down on the cause of the issue; I don't intend to leave it lowered for release